# IEditableObject Sophositicated Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am looking for an [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) implementation with support for dirty data tracking that could work not just for a single object with [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (primitive) properties but entire object graphs that may contain references and collection properties. If there isn't such implementation available, would you provide a few guidelines or hints cause i need this quickly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of possible solutions to this:

- find a component suite that has support for this (I've seen frameworks built on top of the DevExpress suites do this, but not sure if it was baked in)
- find a code generator to help reduce the boilerplate code you need to write (NuGet might be a good place to start).
- use PostSharp to inject code to deal with the problem (or some other AOP tool)
- wrap all your data in Transactional and use a VolatileTransactionManager (IDesign has published code for this solution on their web-site, but I'd be worried about performance)
- make your data structures deeply cloneable, and work on the clone until changes are committed. This solution is probably the easiest to write and debug. A library like [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) includes extensions to deeply clone object graphs, or you could simply serialize/deserialize to generate the copy.

Choices, choices!

Comment: Will check the first option to see what pops up, PostSharps good as this is a cross-cutting concern. I have one question though, you last suggestion i know it is easy to code but how am i going to detect change, dirty tracking is pretty important for me, and perhaps a link or more info about the fourth option ? Thank You

Comment: #5: you would probably have to write logic to recursively compare the object graphs, unless you are able to simply use the new object graph directly (e.g. by writing an updated document to a NoSQL store).